# Generate random number every n second js

Tags: javascript, math, random, setinterval

How can you generate a **new** random number every given second using `Math.random()`? I have tried putting it in a function and return `Math.random` but it return the same thing every time. Is there an efficient way to do this in *short* amount of code?
-thanks

Comment: `Math.random` return a number between 0 and 1. Are you aware of that fact?

Comment: Just put the `Math.random()` expression in the repeatedly executed code instead of before it. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: What was the value of "same thing every time"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 setInterval(function(){   
    console.log(Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)); 

 }, 1000);
```

I ran it in Firefox and it works great.

I will follow TryHunter and edit that the "*100" makes it return 1 to 100, and if you want to say 1 to 1000 change it to 1000.

Comment: could u paste the entire exact code u use? cuz all that is native JS, nothing fancy

Answer (score 3):

```
var number;

(function repeat() {
   number = Math.random();
   setTimeout(repeat, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    number = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    //other code
}, 1000);
```

`Math.random()*100)+1` calculate a number between o and 100, if you want a different range change the number 100 with 10 for example and you can have a range between 0 to 10

Answer (score 0):

> Just `return Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;`
>
> to get random int number from 1 to 100